# Class WC_Payment_Gateway not found

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a custom payment gateway plugin for woocommerce and my class it's telling that the payment class does not exist.

```php
 //add gateway class and register with woocommerce add_action('plugins_loaded', 'init', 0); function init() { if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Payment_Gateway' ) ) return; load_plugin_textdomain( 'payments.gy', FALSE, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/i18n/languages/'
); include_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'classes/class-wc-gateway-paymentsgy.php'; //tell woocommerce that gateway class exist add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateways', array($this, 'wc_gateway_paymentsgy'),1000 ); function wc_gateway_paymentsgy
( $methods ) { $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_Paymentsgy'; return $methods; } }
```

That is how it's being registered.

When I first started this project I built it directly inside the woocommerce plugin folder and it worked but now I'm attempting to make it a "standalone" plugin and I'm getting errors.

Comment: The path to the class was incorrect.

Comment: Then post that as an answer and accept it as the accepted answer. Sometimes, someone answers their own question

Comment: I did, but it was deleted and converted to a comment @kakoma

Comment: That's quite strange. Cool. I had no idea such things happened

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this and remember 1 thing **include your new payment  file** in **wp_loaded** hook

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateways', array($this,'abt_object_payment') );
public function abt_object_payment( $methods) {
    $methods[] = 'Advance_Bank_Transfer_class';
    return $methods;
}
```